# Когда используется союз А ТАКЖЕ

Tags: союзы

Союз А ТАКЖЕ называют присоединительным союзом, то есть имеющим добавочное значение (другие союзы этой группы: ДА И, ДА ЕЩЁ).

**Но союз А ТАКЖЕ не так прост.** Обратим внимание на его **структуру**: его основным элементом является **союз А со значением сопоставления.** (**При сопоставлении** факты различаются по какому-либо признаку, но при этом не являются взаимоисключающими, а сосуществуют).

**ТАКЖЕ ― конкретизатор** со значением присоединения. Так строится этот присоединительный  союз, **но всегда ли он выражает присоединительное значение?**

Рассмотрим примеры:

Рядом лежал вещмешок командира, **а также** санитарная сумка и вещмешок Тумаша. [Василь Быков. Болото (2001)]

В складах скопились водка, спирт, **а также** денатурат. [Даниил Гранин. Зубр (1987)]

И шныряли вербовщики по вагонам, созывали на восстановление народного хозяйства, на новостройки, на рыбалку и на золотые прииски, **а также** в ремесленные училища и в таёжные поисковые экспедиции. [Виктор Астафьев. Пролетный гусь (2000)]

Казалось бы, **зачем в этих однородных рядах выделять основные и добавочные члены,** вроде бы это простое перечисление всех членов ряда.

Попробуем **заменить** А ТАКЖЕ союзом И **или убрать** его вообще:

В складах скопились водка, спирт и денатурат. Рядом лежали вещмешок командира, санитарная сумка и вещмешок Тумаша.

И шныряли вербовщики по вагонам, созывали на восстановление народного хозяйства, на новостройки, на рыбалку и на золотые прииски, в ремесленные училища и в таёжные поисковые экспедиции.

**Вопросы:**

1) **Что изменилось?** Нужен ли был союз А ТАКЖЕ и **какую функцию он выполнял?** Было ли у него присоединительное значение?

2) **Когда вы используете союз А ТАКЖЕ** при построении однородного ряда? Он нужен вам для выражения  присоединительного или какого-то другого значения?

Answer (score 1):

> Попробуем заменить А ТАКЖЕ союзом И или убрать его вообще:

а) В складах скопились водка, спирт, а также денатурат.
б) В складах скопились водка, спирт и денатурат.
в) В складах скопились водка, спирт, денатурат.

> 1) Что изменилось?

Сразу бросается в глаза, насколько разными могут быть интонации в этих предложениях. Интонационный анализ показывает, что в последнем варианте интонация на конце фразы может быть как повышающей, так и понижающей (это важно, поскольку от этого зависит, является ли перечисление завершённым, или нет). В русском языке не используется обозначение интонации в обычных печатных текстах, поэтому нужно выбирать такое построение предложения, которое даёт нужную интонацию. Использование союза **И** или **А ТАКЖЕ** однозначно определяет понижающую интонацию, которая показывает, что перечисление завершено.

Отдельно нужно сказать, что перечисление без союзов предполагает, что перечисляемые объекты не зависят друг от друга, в то время как использование союза **И** объединяет их в одну семантическую группу. Союз **А ТАКЖЕ** действует немного иначе: он объединяет предыдущее множество объектов в одну семантическую группу и добавляет к ним выделенный объект. Это может быть сделано либо с целью противопоставления, либо просто с целью присоединения к упомянутому множеству объекта другой природы.

Теперь мы можем выбрать нужный вариант между п.п. а) и б). Мы видим, что в перечне "водка, спирт, денатурат" последний объект не может (в обычном контексте) объединяться в одну группу с остальными, поскольку это объект совершенно другой природы — он не пригоден для употребления. Следовательно, используем союза А ТАКЖЕ.

При подготовке ответа использовались материалы "Нового объяснительного словаря синонимов русского языка" Апресяна (там этим союзам посвящена многостраничная статья).

**Дополнение.**

> Составной союз **А ТАКЖЕ**, в отличие от **И** и **ДА**, является не клитикой, а
>   полноударным словом. Отчасти в связи с этой фонетической особенностью
>   данный союз объединяет элементы внутри множества в минимальной
>   степени, причём последний элемент множества как бы добавляется к
>   поданным ранее и в какой-то степени им противопоставляется. Ср. *Он
>   знает английский, немецкий, шведский, а также суахили* VS *Он знает
>   английский, немецкий, шведский и суахили.*

Comment: Хотя я интонационным анализом больше не занимаюсь, но могу сказать, что в конце предложения тон только понижающий, это как раз и говорит о завершенности фразы. Что касается семантического объединения, то оно прослеживается далеко не во всех предложениях. Вот в третьем примере идет простое перечисление, я как раз об этом спрашиваю.  Иногда мы делим ряд на тематические группы, но это ведь не добавочное значение, а скорее дифференцирующее.

Comment: Апресян в нескольких абзацах расписывает семантические особенности бессоюзия с интонацией незавершённого перечисления. Это как раз относится к третьему примеру (с перечислением). Я бы посоветовал посмотреть его статью, но раз интонации Вам больше не интересны, то и ладно. Союз А ТАКЖЕ нужен как раз для того, чтобы объединить в одно целое объекты, которые естественным образом не сочетаются. Для более явного дифференцирования лучше использовать структуру "не только ... но и", например.

Comment: Посмотрю я при возможности статью (лично меня-то интонация интересует), просто на этом форуме нет никакого желания об этом говорить. Так неужели открыто явление повышение тона В КОНЦЕ повествовательного предложения, я была уверена, что это возможно только в конце вопросительного предложения. И о семантике: в предложении 3 что с чем  сочетается и потом противопоставляется?

Comment: *И о семантике: в предложении 3 что с чем сочетается и потом противопоставляется?* — ( ну да, Вам знать не положено :) водка и спирт — это алкогольные напитки, а денатурат с этой точки зрения — яд.

Comment: Это предложение 2, а я спрашиваю о своем предложении 3: И шныряли вербовщики по вагонам...

Comment: А, понял. Я думаю, что там весь вопрос только в предлогах НА и В: автор решил таким образом улучшить стилистическую сочетаемость. Не уверен, насколько это корректно, но мне глаз не режет. Хотя, может, в экспедиции и в училища они созывали в последнюю очередь, на худой конец, так сказать.

Comment: Спасибо. У меня, правда, другое мнение на этот счет, позже тогда его озвучу.